# ggplot: stacking multiple plots into the same figure and scaling them appropriately

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've a set of simulations, and I would like to plot certain graphs for each of those simulations using `ggplot2` and put them into the same figure, as a single row.

I've googled it a lot but it seems that every page gives the same old example and none of them clearly explains how to do it.

Here is what I want to do pseudo-code:

```
figure <- newFigure(nrows=dim(filelist)[1])
for(file in filelist)
{
d<- getData()
graph1 <- ggplot2(...)
figure <- rbind(figure, graph1)
graph2 <- ggplot2(...)
figure <- rbind(figure, graph2)
}

scale(figure, way="fit-appropriately")
draw(figure)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an initial `ggplot()` object and add geometries to it.
Try:

```
library(ggplot2)

filelist <- list('red','blue','green')
p <- ggplot()
for (file in filelist)  {
  mydata <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=sample(1:10,10,replace=T))
  p <- p + geom_line(data=mydata,aes(x,y),color=file)
}
p <- p + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-5,15))
p
```

[image]

Comment: Can't I add multiple `ggplot` objects? becuase my plots aren't as simple as to fit into a single `geom_line(...)` object

Comment: this is an example, but you could add any compatible geometry you'd like. The trick is not to add the ggplot() but to add the geometries.

Comment: then how to you pass your data that's in a dataframe?

Comment: like `ggplot(d, aes(x=Time, y=Pos, color=...))`, where `d` having columns with names `Time` and `Pos`